# Intuitive answer doesn't match with logical reasoning I used

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm Trying to see validity of the following argument:


***If i get chirstmas bonus, I'll buy stereo 

If i sell my motorcycle, I'll buy stereo 

therefore if i get a christmas bonus or I sell my motor cycle then I'll buy a stereo***

This sounds valid even without any reasoning but when i applied i got a different answer.


*CB = Getting chirstmas bonus

BS = Buying Stereo

SM = Selling motor cycle*

$CB \rightarrow BS$
$SM \rightarrow BS$
$CB \lor SM \rightarrow BS$
Given 
$$CB {\rightarrow} BS$$
$$SM \rightarrow BS$$
**Through Generalization**
$$\therefore (CB \rightarrow BS) \lor (SM \rightarrow BS)$$
$$(\neg CB\lor BS) \lor (\neg SM\lor BS)$$
$$(\neg CB \lor \neg SM) \lor(BS\lor BS)$$
$$(\neg CB \lor \neg SM)\lor(BS)$$
$$\neg (CB \land SM)\lor BS$$
$$\therefore CB \land SM \rightarrow BS$$

This answer doesn't match inuitively, Where did i go wrong?

Comment: The argument is valid; it is an instance of [Proof by cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination)

Comment: The conclusion you reached is not wrong (if you get a Christmas bonus AND sell the motorcycle, you'll definitely buy the radio), it's just not the one you wanted. Why did you start by combining your two premises with an "or"?

Comment: "Generalization" is not the correct rule to be used.

Comment: your conclusion is a valid consequence of the premises; it's just not the one you're interested in. Instead of inferring $(CB \to BS) \vee (SM \to BS)$ via *disjunction introduction*, also referred to as *addition*, try inferring $(CB \to BS) \wedge (SM \to BS)$ via *conjunction introduction* and proceed from there.

Answer (score 2):

You have both $CB\rightarrow BS$ and $SM\rightarrow BS$, therefore you should start with $(CB\rightarrow BS)\land (SM\rightarrow BS)$.

What you showed is that if you have either of those, then you'll need both $CB$ and $SM$ to conclude $BS$, which is intuitive to me at least as well.

---

Now you have to prove

$$CB→ BS,SM→ BS ⊢ CB∨ SM→ BS$$

To see this follows, you split in cases your hypothesis $CB∨ SM$.

First case. If $CB$ then by $CB→ BS$ you get $BS$ as expected.

Second case. If $SM$ then by $SM→ BS$ you get $BS$ as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed: since you have *both* premises as givens, you should start with $(CB\rightarrow BS)\land (SM\rightarrow BS)$ rather than $(CB\rightarrow BS)\lor (SM\rightarrow BS)$

And with that, you get:

$(CB\rightarrow BS)\land (SM\rightarrow BS) \Leftrightarrow$

$(\neg CB\lor BS)\land (\neg SM\lor BS) \Leftrightarrow$

$(\neg CB\land \neg SM) \lor BS \Leftrightarrow$

$\neg (CB\lor  SM) \lor BS \Leftrightarrow$

$(CB\lor  SM) \to BS$

I am wondering why you started with $(CB\rightarrow BS)\lor (SM\rightarrow BS)$ ... is it because you saw the 'or' in the desired conclusion "if i get a christmas bonus or I sell my motor cycle then I'll buy a stereo"?   If so, then well, yes, you end up with an 'or' o=in the conclusion ($(CB \color{red}\lor  SM) \to BS$) ... but this 'or' is really part of the antecedent of the conclusion.  But as far as your starting point goes: you have two premises, and so you know that *both* of $CB\rightarrow BS$ and $SM\rightarrow BS$ are, so the starting point should be $(CB\rightarrow BS)\color{red}\land (SM\rightarrow BS)$

And yes, it may seem surprising that $(CB\rightarrow BS) \color{red}\land (SM\rightarrow BS)$ ends up being equivalent to $(CB \color{red}\lor  SM) \to BS$, as it doesn't follow the 'normal' distribution pattern ... but apparently this is what it works out to.